# Bootstrap columns are stacking, they should be aligned horizontally

Tags: bootstrap-4

My images are in three col-4s, which should make them all fit in a row, but for some reason they stack instead. I was trying to hide the content below md display, but .d-block seems break the row layout.

[Image of the inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFk3a.png)

Code:

```
    <div class="row d-none d-md-block">

        <div class="col-4">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="images/website images/userResearch1.jpg" alt="User Research Qualitative Notes"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="images/website images/userResearch2.jpg" alt="User Research Qualitative Notes"/>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
            <img class="img-fluid" src="images/website images/userResearch3.jpg" alt="User Research Qualitative Notes"/>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `d-block`. It's overriding the normal `display:flex` on the Bootstrap `.row`. If you want to hide/show responsively use `row d-none d-md-flex`.

Comment: but then how do I make it display on md+?

Comment: make what display? do you mean you want a different layout on `md` and up? please edit and clarify the question.

Comment: clarification: I was trying to hide the content below md display, but and .block seemed to be the "show" function, so I added that I wanted flexed after the block and it worked out

Answer (score -1):

Added a flex to the row

```
<div class="row d-none d-md-block d-md-flex">

    <div class="col-4">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="images/website images/userResearch1.jpg" alt="User Research Qualitative Notes"/>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="images/website images/userResearch2.jpg" alt="User Research Qualitative Notes"/>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
        <img class="img-fluid" src="images/website images/userResearch3.jpg" alt="User Research Qualitative Notes"/>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Worth noting that without the md clarification to the flex, the images appeared in format below md